# Is Google's V8 engine really limited to 1 VM per process?

Tags: javascript, c++, v8

I can't get a straight forward answer on this. Is Google's V8 engine really limited to 1 VM per process?

If google's v8 engine is limited to only 1 VM per process, then doesn't it sort of exclude itself from being used in libraries? Say I code up a c++ library that uses V8 called LibA. And someone else codes up another library that uses V8 called LibB. If an application links to both LibA and LibB bad stuff would happen (right?).

I need a fast (with speed being the most important requirement actually) javascript parser for a lib I'm trying to write, but I don't want to use v8 if I'll run into this problem (it's likely that the kind of applications that link to it will also use v8 at some point).

Comment: Check out [this thread](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=510).

Comment: This is *quite* on topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this [closed bug report](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=510), it's safe to say that Google's V8 engine is not limited to a single thread per process (since approximately April 2011).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Do you know if you have to explicitly make use of 'isolates' when you want to account for having multiple instances in one process, or does it 'just work'?

Comment: @Pris: Isolates don't necessarily correlate to threads (you can use one isolate in different threads so long as you use a Locker to ensure exclusive access from one thread at a time), therefore you have to explicitly set up the isolates that you want to use so that you can specify which one you want to use from a specific thread at a specific time.